# Hires, interlaced screen on Amiga Devpac, with window, menu and buttons

Tags: assembly, motorola, amiga

Using **DevPac 3**, I need to produce an application that displays graphics in a similar way to DPaint. No right-hand toolbar, just a vertically scrolling image, preferably in HAM mode.

Application digest:

- Open a new hires interlaced screen in as many colours as hardware will allow
- Basic menu structure that I can manipulate (Top Right-click menu)
- A project window, similar to the DevPac editor
- A control panel along the top similar to the one in Digita Wordworth with text boxes, buttons and tabs
- I also need an off screen buffer that is as wide as the screen and as tall as memory will allow.

This needs to be compatible with:

- Workbench 3.0 and above
- 68020 and above
- ECS & AGA chipset
- 0.5..2Mb chipmem + 0..∞ fastmem

I don't know where to begin, and any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: On ECS and OCS, you can't have Hires (640 pixels wide without overscan) and HAM at the same time. On those older graphics architectures 16 colors is the maximum in Hires mode, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide may give you a few hint specially about "intuition" programming : http://gulasoft.uw.hu/AmigaDoc/AmigaAsmTutorial.txt

You can also find exhaustive documentation about kernel libraries here : http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/

I hope it helps

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to you since you were the only person who tried. Between us we'll improve this answer